# I want to fetch API and destructure it

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to fetch this API:

```
const getAUserProfile = () => {
  const api='https://randomuser.me/api/';

  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(resonse => response.json()) // make API call here
```

and destructure it using these functions, assigning the location, date of birth and phone number to these functions:

```
const displayBirthdate = () => {}
const displayPhone = () => {}
const displayAddress = () => {}
```

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you be more specific about objective, use case , and expected results? Also tell us where you are running into problems currently

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the API of 'https://randomuser.me/api/'  and 
1: Modify it to use object de-structuring to get just the dob property of the parameter object it will receive. for the displayBirthdate function
2: locate the displayAddress function and de-structure its parameter to get just the location property
3:  locate the displayPhone function and de-structure its parameter to get just the phone and cell properties

Comment: Ok .. so are you having problems accessing those properties in the response object?

Comment: yes, just heard about destructuring today and don't know how to go about it

Comment: Still not clear what you had in mind with the functions. Check out trobol's answer and see if that gets you what you need

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your response and I think you should more on destructuring. [Check out this page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

In a sentence, destructuring assigns values from an object or array to variables.

```js
const getAUserProfile = () => {
  const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
  console.log("boop");
  return fetch(api)
    .then((response) => {

      return response.json();

    });
}
getAUserProfile().then((result) => {

  console.log(result.results[0]);

  //note the object has values dob, phone and location
  let {
    dob,
    phone,
    location
  } = result.results[0]; //Destructuring assignment

  displayBirthdate(dob);
  displayBirthdate(phone);
  displayAddress(location);
});

function displayBirthdate(dob) {
  console.log(dob);
}

function displayBirthdate(phone) {
  console.log(phoneb);
}

function displayAddress(location) {
  console.log(location);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
this is cool but the d.o.b, phone and location were meant to be in those 3 functions separately

Comment: What do you mean by "in" those functions? I don't see a point in having 3 functions if one request fetches all the data. If you are trying to display the data in those function then I would save the user and call the functions with the user as a parameter.

Comment: Please can you show me how you would save the user and call the functions with the user as a parameter

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you could display the user data using functions.